# how to return into commit by hash and push it into branch

Tags: git, version-control

I get into trouble by working at project with eclipse and git.

I had commited 2 changes into head and trying to push it into master but it give me failure in eclipse. So at result i didn't push my changes into any branch.

Then I type:

```
git checkout master
```

so that was wrong because I 'lost'my changes.

But when I type:

```
git reflog show
```

I see:

```
 .....(some of my trying to return to 2bbca5f version)
 5fe803c HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from master to new-year-master
 a337a12 HEAD@{12}: pull: Fast-forward
 2909fde HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from 2bbca5f6c22a226b8b4ea0e7786dbeb5c7b0187b to master
 2bbca5f HEAD@{14}: commit: #: configurable setup for based application  // << my latest changes
 8902806 HEAD@{15}: commit: #: Structural refactor
 a337a12 HEAD@{16}: commit: #: remote test
 d3ad16a HEAD@{17}: commit: #: reconfig
 0e85a5c HEAD@{18}: commit: #: serial
 468d0c6 HEAD@{19}: commit: #:  interface 
 c807292 HEAD@{20}: commit: #:  Changes
```

My question is how to return sources to commit

```
 2bbca5f HEAD@{14}
```

and push it correctly into master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that particular commit on your `master` branch, then after checking out to the branch, do a [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) onto that commit:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick HEAD@{14}
```

And after confirming that you've got the required changes, do a `git push`.

Comment: Thank You I had two commits that I had to merge: 2bbca5f HEAD@{14} and 
 8902806 HEAD@{15}. And I done with this. Is possible to use something like git reset ... to move head to 2bbca5f

Comment: @MazerytFreager Can you update your question showing what you've right now? After merging, a new commit id should have been created. Do you want to move head to previous commit - `2bbca5f`?

Comment: I correctly merge those commits, and everything was ok, I just thinking about single command to return to state 2bbca5f HEAD@{14} without merging those commits

Comment: `git reset --hard 2bbca5f` would do fine. But with that, you'll lose any commits after that (e.g., merge commit). Other way is to create a branch from that commit - `git checkout -b <branch_name> 2bbca5f`.

Comment: Also, with `git reset --hard`, you'll lose all the local modification. If you need that, do just a `git reset`.